# Firebase-hosted website inaccessible, browser warning 'This site can’t provide a secure connection'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple firebase-react website, where users can register, sign in, and make post/delete requests to my firestore. I have the website hosted at Heroku and have a custom domain name. When I try to access my website however, the browser returns the following error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
www.gigfort.nz sent an invalid response.
```

I recently changed the firestore rules to the following, to try and solve this issue - it however didn't work:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

This code is form the firebase docs, and allows mixed private and public access.

So I'm wondering - am I right in assuming this issue is to do with my firestore rule set up, and if so, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: That error message doesn't have anything to do with security rules, since rules are consulted to serve web content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your hosting provider is not provisioning an SSL certificate for the web site. It **is** accessible through HTTP, but not through HTTPS. I haven't set anything up on Heroku myself, but this link looks promising: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

As Doug commented, this error has nothing to do with your Firestore security rules. You'd have the same message accessing a static HTML page without any Firestore in it.